# Recognize incorrect lists and inform users

Tags: feature-request, editor, list

A lot of (relatively) new users post answers looking like

```
1) Item 1
2) Item 2
```

which renders as

> 1) Item 1
>   2) Item 2

or if they notice the problem

```
1) Item 1<br> <!-- or with an empty line, but this I see more often -->
2) Item 2
```

or variations thereof (once I have seen recently and remember right now: `**1**`, `1.)`, `•` (the bullet character copy pasted from a word document or other sources) and of course just `1`).

Now, I was thinking how useful it would be even if only the `1)` (it's the one I see an order of magnitude more often than the others) syntax would be recognized and the user informed about the proper syntax. (Or maybe go crazy and actually fix it for them... but I am not sure whether that's the best idea), Oh well, it's just an idea, what do you guys think, worth it?

Answer (score 2):

> what do you guys think, worth it?

Dunno, does it happen much? I've not seen it a lot, but if it's happening a fair bit perhaps something could be done to "assist".

> Or maybe go crazy and actually fix it for them

Sounds ideal, in principle.
But my immediate thought is how do you identify if they want a HTML list, or just a `1)`?

There must be scenarios where people want to use a `1)` or `1.` but not have a HTML list. And forcing something onto someone can be annoying as it removes flexibility in the markdown.

Whereas now, those just wanting `1)` and no list can, and those wanting a list just use the `CTRL o` or control panel.

---

Also, the markdown is actually a dot, so we'd be changing it from `1)` to `1.`, which is different text.

The problem with this is people don't know why things are changing.  They submit, or see the preview, and fight with the system - they change it, the system says "What are you doing Dave" and changes it back...

I'm not convinced (yet) automating this would work.

> Now, I was thinking how useful it would be even if only the 1) (it's
>   the one I see an order of magnitude more often than the others) syntax
>   would be recognized and the user informed about the proper syntax.

I'd vote in favour for identifying when a user does type `1)` or `1.` at the start of a line, and initiate a pop-up message box:

> `To create a HTML list, do XYZ`

Comment: I dunno, I see it quite often, but that might be because it irritates me more than most when there is a sentence with an inline list, so I always go in to fix it... where I next notice that they user quite often actually intended it to be a normal list (using enters between the various lines), but markdown rendered it as a long sentence.

Comment: I see it moderately often, so I think a warning would be fine, yes. (Auto-correcting really doesn't seem warranted.)